# Full Screen Mode in Flash AS2

Tags: flash

Is it possible to make play swf in full screen mode when HTML page lunch?

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible, the fullscreen mode must be initiated by the user.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible...make a javascript to flash routine then call a click event inside the flash file. When your page loads call this routine to flash and walla :)